# Is it possible to create fullscreen webpart page?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a requirement for a fullscreen webpart. Currently the solution was to hack an extension to hide sharepoint side menu.
Now the client is complaining about the extension performance and we see that the fullscreen webparts are available.

There is only one problem with this solution - it requires the site to be recreated as a communication site -> [**source**](https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/how-add-spfx-webpart-full-width-column)
Is it possible to create/hack a sitepage to be have a fullscreen (fullwidth) section? We have a lot of content on the page so the migration process would be a little painfull.

[image: Currently looking intranet page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a office ui fabric panel to get this working. It's not ideal but does the trick. Essentially I have a fullscreen button which allows the user to toggle between fullscreen and regular. The component is wrapped in the panel when 'on' and the panel is removed when 'off'. Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right but for the single component. My requirement is to have a webpart on a page with multiple webparts unfortunately and the panel approach is pretty neat when it comes to showing only one webpart on a page.
Thanks btw bc i didnt know about the portal for office fabric :) https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/panel

Comment: Ok, yeah unfortunately it won't work for displaying multiple webparts in full screen.